# Hibernate findById() issue

Tags: hibernate

I am getting issue during any Crud operation through findbyId() method in hibernate(not always); and it is comming out unexpectedly(at any uncertain time, 10% chances of issue raising).
    But after reloading the page(send request again from browser) it gets the desired data; no issue.

```
I have checked with all methods of hibernate(4.1.7) for findById such as get(), load(), byId.load(), criteria, but invain.
given my testing code snippet:

public SurveyDefination findById(final long sdId) throws HibernateException {
        /*
         * Session session1 = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
         * session1.beginTransaction();
         */
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(SurveyDefination.class).add(
                Restrictions.idEq(sdId));
        SurveyDefination surveyDefination = (SurveyDefination) criteria
                .uniqueResult();

        if (surveyDefination == null) {
            int count = 0;
            System.out
                    .println("Before------surveyDefination--------Output --------- :: "
                            + count++ + ":  " + surveyDefination);
        //  session.evict(surveyDefination);
            if (surveyDefination == null && count == 1) {
                surveyDefination = (SurveyDefination) session.get(
                        SurveyDefination.class, sdId);
                System.out
                        .println("Before------surveyDefination--------Output -----get()---- :: "
                                + count++ + ":  " + surveyDefination);
            }
            if (surveyDefination == null)
                try {
                    surveyDefination = (SurveyDefination) session.load(
                            SurveyDefination.class, sdId);
                    System.out
                            .println("Before------surveyDefination--------Output -----load()---- :: "
                                    + count++ + ":  " + surveyDefination);
                } catch (HibernateException e) {
                    logger.error(e.getMessage() + "  ObjectNotFoundException");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            if (surveyDefination == null) {
                surveyDefination = (SurveyDefination) session.byId(
                        SurveyDefination.class).load(sdId);
                logger.info("Before------surveyDefination--------Output -----byId().load()---- :: "
                        + count++ + ":  " + surveyDefination);
            }

            if (surveyDefination == null) {

                criteria = session.createCriteria(SurveyDefination.class).add(
                        Restrictions.idEq(sdId));
                surveyDefination = (SurveyDefination) criteria.uniqueResult();
                System.out
                        .println("Before------surveyDefination--------Output -----createCriteria()---- :: "
                                + count++ + ":  " + surveyDefination);
            }
        }
        System.out
                .println("After -----surveyDefination---------Output --------- :: "
                        + surveyDefination);

        return surveyDefination;
    }


But after all checking if it gets null once, it will never get the result;
but same request by resending immediately, desired output comes out.

Following is the error from my console, plz give a reason for such issue. 

11:06:50,987 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4) connection is idle true connection release count 2

11:06:51,012 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4) Before------surveyDefination--------Output --------- :: 0:  null

11:06:51,018 INFO  [stdout] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4) Before------surveyDefination--------Output -----get()---- :: 1:  null

11:06:51,027 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4) org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [com.ttn.survey.model.SurveyDefination#322]

11:06:51,027 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl$1$1.handleEntityNotFound(SessionFactoryImpl.java:242)

11:06:51,028 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.checkTargetState(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:248)

11:06:51,028 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:176)

11:06:51,029 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:272)

11:06:51,029 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:185)

11:06:51,030 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at com.ttn.survey.model.SurveyDefination_$$_javassist_95.toString(SurveyDefination_$$_javassist_95.java)

11:06:51,030 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2847)

11:06:51,030 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:128)

11:06:51,031 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at com.ttn.survey.controller.implementations.dao.SurveyDefinationDAOImpl.findById(SurveyDefinationDAOImpl.java:132)

11:06:51,031 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at com.ttn.survey.controller.implementations.client.ClientSurveyActionImpl.findSurveyInfoById(ClientSurveyActionImpl.java:213)

11:06:51,032 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at com.ttn.survey.view.client.SurveyControllerServlet.doGet(SurveyControllerServlet.java:199)

11:06:51,032 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)

11:06:51,032 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)

11:06:51,033 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)

11:06:51,033 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)

11:06:51,034 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:840)

11:06:51,034 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:622)

11:06:51,034 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:560)

11:06:51,035 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)

11:06:51,035 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:213)

11:06:51,036 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:171)

11:06:51,036 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)

11:06:51,037 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)

11:06:51,037 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)

11:06:51,037 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)

11:06:51,038 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)

11:06:51,038 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)

11:06:51,039 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)

11:06:51,039 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)

11:06:51,039 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)

11:06:51,040 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)

11:06:51,041 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)

11:06:51,041 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)

11:06:51,042 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)

11:06:51,042 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)

11:06:51,043 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)

11:06:51,043 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

11:06:51,043 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4) org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [com.ttn.survey.model.SurveyDefination#322]

11:06:51,044 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl$1$1.handleEntityNotFound(SessionFactoryImpl.java:242)

11:06:51,044 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.checkTargetState(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:248)

11:06:51,045 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:180)

11:06:51,045 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:272)

11:06:51,046 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:185)

11:06:51,046 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at com.ttn.survey.model.SurveyDefination_$$_javassist_95.toString(SurveyDefination_$$_javassist_95.java)

11:06:51,047 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2847)

11:06:51,047 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:128)

11:06:51,047 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at com.ttn.survey.controller.implementations.dao.SurveyDefinationDAOImpl.findById(SurveyDefinationDAOImpl.java:157)

11:06:51,048 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at com.ttn.survey.controller.implementations.client.ClientSurveyActionImpl.findSurveyInfoById(ClientSurveyActionImpl.java:213)

11:06:51,048 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at com.ttn.survey.view.client.SurveyControllerServlet.doGet(SurveyControllerServlet.java:199)

11:06:51,049 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)

11:06:51,049 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)

11:06:51,049 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)

11:06:51,050 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)

11:06:51,050 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:840)

11:06:51,051 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:622)

11:06:51,051 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:560)

11:06:51,051 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:488)

11:06:51,052 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:213)

11:06:51,052 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:171)

11:06:51,053 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)

11:06:51,053 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)

11:06:51,054 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)

11:06:51,054 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)

11:06:51,054 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)

11:06:51,055 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)

11:06:51,055 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)

11:06:51,056 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153)

11:06:51,057 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)

11:06:51,058 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)

11:06:51,058 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)

11:06:51,059 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)

11:06:51,059 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)

11:06:51,059 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)

11:06:51,060 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)

11:06:51,060 ERROR [stderr] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: It might be data binding issue (from the managed session), not yet sure.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this

```
 surveyDefination = (SurveyDefination) session.load(
                            SurveyDefination.class, sdId);
```

You can't load a not existing persistent with load() method. So you get an exception in toString() of SurveyDefination in this (as i think, cause you don't provide line numbers)

```
System.out.println("Before------surveyDefination--------Output 
-----load()---- :: " + count++ + ":  " + surveyDefination);
```

P.S. If you want to see some techniques of working with Hibernate you can see it [here](https://www.livecoding.tv/ladynev/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Yes, I agree with you ; but my problem is that after reloading the page how does it get the data ??  I guess that sometimes it does not bind data so that such problems occurr, but after refreshing/ resending the same request it gets correct output...HOW ???

Comment: @DebajyotiMohanty I think a problem not with this code but with other parts (injection session, transactions etc.).

Comment: Thanks @v.ladynev for ur suggestion. I think problem may be with session operations; because I am getting ("sdId") value which i push into my method findById(final long sdId).

This ("sdId") value is not null(as coming from browser). After I'm doing any session opertaions, something happens and my object ("surveyDefination") becomes null(and it happens rarely not always).
Thats's why I'm fully confused over here.
Anyway Thanks again for ur info. Still hope for exact causes of problem.